# Errors while updating IBM HTTP Plugin and IBH IHS

Tags: java, websphere, ihs

Initially this activity started with installing the WAS 7.0.0.39 fixpack on our system.

The UpdateInstaller was successfully upgraded to 7.0.0.39, along with WAS and java.

WAS is installed using `wassrvr` id, while the webserver is installed using `webserver` id.

After I switched id to `webserver` and tried to install the fixpack for the IBM HTTP plugin and the IHS server using the `update.sh` command, I got the following errors:

```
[$WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller]$ ./update.sh

Executing command: $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/bin/java -cp $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/update.jar -Xms48m -Xmx384m run

JVMJ9VM019E Unrecoverable error: Unable to find and initialize required class java/lang/Object
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ppc64/default/jclSC160/vm.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/annotation.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/beans.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/java.util.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/jndi.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/logging.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/security.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/sql.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmorb.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmorbapi.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmcfw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/rt.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/charsets.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/resources.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmpkcs.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmcertpathfw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjgssfw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjssefw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmsaslfw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjcefw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjgssprovider.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjsseprovider2.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmcertpathprovider.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/xml.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/jlm.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/javascript.jar
JVMJ9VM023I This may indicate that JAVA_HOME is incorrect, or that class libraries are not installed
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library jclscar_24(14): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

So I tried checking the java version as `wassrvr`

```
[/home/wassrvr]$ java -version
java version "1.5.0"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pap64devifx-20130702 (SR16 FP3 ))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc64-64 j9vmap6423ifx-20130613 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20130611_151893_BHdSMr
JIT  - 20121221_30553_r8
GC   - 20120911_AA)
JCL  - 20130702
```

And again using the absolute path of java:

```
[/home/wassrvr]$ $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6460sr16fp7ifix-20150930_02(SR16 FP7+IV77565))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc64-64 jvmap6460sr16fp7-20150701_255724 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20150701_255724
JIT  - r9_20150630_95420
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR16_20150701_1008_B255724)
JCL  - 20150628_01
```

Tried the same as `webserver`

```
[/home/webserver]$ java -version
ksh: java:  not found
```

Using the absolute path:

```
[/home/webserver]$ $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/bin/java -version
JVMJ9VM019E Unrecoverable error: Unable to find and initialize required class java/lang/Object
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ppc64/default/jclSC160/vm.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/annotation.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/beans.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/java.util.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/jndi.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/logging.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/security.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/sql.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmorb.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmorbapi.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmcfw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/rt.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/charsets.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/resources.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmpkcs.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmcertpathfw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjgssfw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjssefw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmsaslfw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjcefw.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjgssprovider.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmjsseprovider2.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/ibmcertpathprovider.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/xml.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/jlm.jar
JVMJ9VM020I Searched in $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/lib/javascript.jar
JVMJ9VM023I This may indicate that JAVA_HOME is incorrect, or that class libraries are not installed
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library jclscar_24(14): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

While installing the WAS fix pack, there were no errors. But while trying to install the Plugin and IHS upgrade, the tmp logfile is not being created.

I am at a stump here, some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you put the wrong UPDI update on?  Maybe run /usr/bin/file on a bunch of the shared libs and java exe and make sure they agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I was able to resolve the issue. After checking the permission of each file one by one, found out that a directory `j9vm` under `$WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/bin` had a `700` permission. After changing this to `755` I was able to execute the update script.

Answer (score 0):

Please check JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH environment variables of wassrvr user and set it to the same values after switching to webserver account. This is the first step I would do as error description is pointing that essential java class cannot be loaded.

Comment: neither values are set in `wassrvr` id. the `update.sh` script that is sued to update the IHS and plugin, generates these values for itself. The script is provided by IBM and comes along with the updateinstaller package. 

Sample of the syntax it creats is `Executing command: $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/bin/java -cp $WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/update.jar -Xms48m -Xmx384m run`

Comment: both the Java home and class path are explicitly mentioned in the commad that it runs.

Comment: I can see that CLASSPATH is set, however don't see any reference to JAVA_HOME. Could you try setting it via
`export JAVA_HOME=$WAS_HOME/UpdateInstaller/java/` and then try to execute it again? This of course assume that WAS_HOME is set already - if not change it to appropriate path.
Alternatively set JAVA_HOME to the one distributed with the WAS and not the Update Installer.